# How do I add the request.slug to a generic class view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

I have a view that getts all my projects by a slug that is the tag. When I show the template, I want to include that tag in my template so that I can do something like: "Content in {{tag.name}}. But I'm having a hard time seeing my way clear. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my view:

```
class TagDetail(ListView):
    """ Get all projects for a tag """

    template_name = "projects/TagDetail.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        tags = get_list_or_404(Project, tags__slug=self.kwargs['slug'], displayed=True)
        return tags

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TagDetail, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need something in the template context, then look into modifying the context.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView.get_context_data

Note that you're not actually accessing a tag object, so you'll have to query for your tag.

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['slug'] = self.kwargs['slug'] # or Tag.objects.get(slug=...)
    return ctx

<!-- template -->
The slug is: {{ slug }}
```

Comment: This works! But I want to make sure I understand what is happening.

Comment: 'def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs): ## Use the get context method - use itself and look for args and kwargs
    ctx = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs) #get the context for my view
    ctx['slug'] = self.kwargs['slug'] # or Tag.objects.get(slug=...)
    return ctx - add the slug to it (or go get a tag with that slug'

Comment: @DaveMerwin - I'm not sure I understand the question. You marked it as accepted, so I'm hoping you figured it out? GL!